# Getter/Setter make Unity 2020.2.20 crashes

Tags: c#, properties

I have 2 scripts as follow:

config.cs

```
public enum CONTROL_TYPE : int
{
    TOUCH_CONTROL = 0,
    TILT_CONTROL = 1,
};
    
public CONTROL_TYPE controlType
{
    get { return controlType; }
    set { controlType = value; }
}
```

menu.cs

```
config gameConfig
    
void Start()
{   
    gameConfig.controlType = GameConfig.CONTROL_TYPE.TOUCH_CONTROL;
}
```

I am trying to set the `controlType` , but the Unity editor always crashes when it happen.
Can anyone help to point where I get this wrong?

Comment: It crashes because the property getter/setter are self-referencing. You need a backing field, or change it to `{ get; set; }` to have one created for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your property getter and setter are **self referencing**.
This will cause an infinite recursion.

**You can solve it in 2 ways:**

1. Add an explicit data member that will hold the property value:

   ```
   private CONTROL_TYPE controlType; // this is the new data member
   public CONTROL_TYPE ControlType
   {
       get { return controlType; }
       set { controlType = value; }
   }
   ```
2. Let the compiler generate it for you behind the scene, by using this more succinct syntax (equivalent to the 1st option):

   ```
   public CONTROL_TYPE ControlType { get; set; }
   ```

In your case, I would prefer the more elegant 2nd option.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it's a silly mistake. I forgot to make variable for the properties and instead trying to fill the properties itself.

It should be like this:

config.cs

```
public enum CONTROL_TYPE : int
{
    TOUCH_CONTROL = 0,
    TILT_CONTROL = 1,
};

private CONTROL_TYPE _controlType; // This one here
public CONTROL_TYPE ControlType
{
    get { return _controlType; }
    set { _controlType = value; }
}
```

menu.cs

```
...
....

    config gameConfig

    void Start()
    {   
        gameConfig.ControlType = GameConfig.CONTROL_TYPE.TOUCH_CONTROL;
    }
...
....
```